# Escaping inner loop and go to the outer loop after action is done

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, nested-for-loop

There is a code for the BigestCountries class.

It consists of 2 arrays:

```
private String[][] biggestCountries; - holds country name and the continent, e.g. biggestCountries[CHINA][COUNTRY_NAME] = "China"; biggestCountries[CHINA][COUNTRY_CONTINENT] = "Asia";

private int[][] countryData; - holds populations and year founded, e.g. countryData[CHINA][COUNTRY_POPULATION] = 1433783686; countryData[CHINA][COUNTRY_AGE_FOUNDED] = 1949;
```

```
public String[] getCountriesFoundedBetween(int min, int max){
    int countriesMatched;
    countriesMatched = 0;  
    String[] countriesFoundedBetween;

    if(biggestCountries == null || biggestCountries.length == 0){
         return null;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < biggestCountries.length; i++){
        if(countryData[i][COUNTRY_AGE_FOUNDED] >= min && countryData[i][COUNTRY_AGE_FOUNDED] <= max){

            System.out.println(String.format("%d %s", countryData[i][COUNTRY_AGE_FOUNDED], biggestCountries[i][COUNTRY_NAME]));
            countriesMatched++;
        }
    }

    if(countriesMatched > 0){
        countriesFoundedBetween = new String[countriesMatched];
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < biggestCountries.length; i++) { // outer loop for countries array length of NUMBER_OF_COUNTRIES

        String countryMatched = null;
        System.out.println("biggestCountries[i] " + biggestCountries[i][COUNTRY_NAME]);

        if(countryData[i][COUNTRY_AGE_FOUNDED] >= min && countryData[i][COUNTRY_AGE_FOUNDED] <= max){
            for(int j = 0; j < countriesFoundedBetween.length; j++){ // how to escape inner loop?

                countryMatched =  biggestCountries[i][COUNTRY_NAME];
                countriesFoundedBetween[j] = countryMatched;
                System.out.println("countriesFoundedBetween: " + countriesFoundedBetween[j] + "; biggestCountries[i][COUNTRY_NAME]: " + biggestCountries[i][COUNTRY_NAME]);

            }      
        }      
    }

    return countriesFoundedBetween;
}
```

Unfortunately, It cannot escape from the inner loop and re-writes the matched country to all rows of the newly-generated array.
[image: Result]

Comment: You have three loops, and you want to escape to the outermost loop after some condition is met in the innermost loop?

Comment: Yes, there are countries that have information spread over 2 different arrays. And I need to iterate through one array - capture some data and then to iterate through another array and add countries' names to my last array `countriesFoundedBetween`. On the screenshot above the length is right - there are indeed 6 countries that match the criteria. But ofc these not all are Australias.

Comment: Why not just break from the innermost loop after setting a flag that the first nested loop can test and, when true, break to the first loop?

Comment: You just need a labelled `break`.

Comment: good idea, but I believe I don't know how to properly implement it. I tried this https://jmp.sh/pNqmiCB but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user207421break in the inner loop? it doesn't work and populate only first country namehttps://jmp.sh/j6ZmJL8

Comment: @feedthemachine What doesn't work? Show your code. We can't read your mind. I only gave you a very general instruction, and you can't possibly be claiming that break in an inner loop doesn't work in general.

Comment: And if you can't make a labelled break work, which is exactly what you asked for, you were asking the wrong question.

Comment: Use a search engine to find information about labeled breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getCountriesFoundedBetween()` can be implemented differently, without the need for nested loops, as follows.

```java
private static String[] getCountriesFoundedBetween(int min, int max) {
    if (max < min) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'max' less than 'min'");
    }
    String[] countriesFoundedBetween;
    int countriesMatched = 0;
    int[] indexes = new int[biggestCountries.length];
    if (biggestCountries != null && biggestCountries.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < biggestCountries.length; i++) {
            if(countryData[i][COUNTRY_AGE_FOUNDED] >= min &&
               countryData[i][COUNTRY_AGE_FOUNDED] <= max) {
                indexes[countriesMatched++] = i;
            }
        }
        countriesFoundedBetween = new String[countriesMatched];
        for (int i = 0; i < countriesMatched; i++) {
            countriesFoundedBetween[i] = biggestCountries[indexes[i]][COUNTRY_NAME];
        }
    }
    else {
        countriesFoundedBetween = new String[0];
    }
    return countriesFoundedBetween;
}
```

The above code also returns an empty array rather than null which is preferable for methods that return arrays.

Here is a complete example using population to determine the biggest countries.

```java
public class Countrys {
    private static final int  CHINA      = 0;
    private static final int  INDIA      = 1;
    private static final int  U_S_A      = 2;
    private static final int  INDONESIA  = 3;
    private static final int  PAKISTAN   = 4;
    private static final int  BRAZIL     = 5;
    private static final int  NIGERIA    = 6;
    private static final int  BANGLADESH = 7;
    private static final int  RUSSIA     = 8;
    private static final int  MEXICO     = 9;

    private static final int  COUNTRY_NAME = 0;
    private static final int  COUNTRY_CONTINENT = 1;
    private static final int  COUNTRY_POPULATION = 0;
    private static final int  COUNTRY_AGE_FOUNDED = 1;

    private static int[][] countryData = new int[][]{{1_427_647_786, 1949},
                                                     {1_352_642_280, 1950},
                                                     {  328_239_523, 1776},
                                                     {  273_523_615, 1945},
                                                     {  220_892_340, 1947},
                                                     {  210_147_125, 1889},
                                                     {  206_139_589, 1960},
                                                     {  164_689_383, 1971},
                                                     {  144_384_244, 1991},
                                                     {  128_932_753, 1810}};
    private static String[][] biggestCountries = new String[][]{{"China"     , "Asia"},
                                                                {"India"     , "Asia"},
                                                                {"U.S.A."    , "North America"},
                                                                {"Indonesia" , "Asia"},
                                                                {"Pakistan"  , "Asia"},
                                                                {"Brazil"    , "South America"},
                                                                {"Nigeria"   , "Africa"},
                                                                {"Bangladesh", "Asia"},
                                                                {"Russia"    , "Europe"},
                                                                {"Mexico"    , "North America"}};

    private static String[] getCountriesFoundedBetween(int min, int max) {
        if (max < min) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'max' less than 'min'");
        }
        String[] countriesFoundedBetween;
        int countriesMatched = 0;
        int[] indexes = new int[biggestCountries.length];
        if (biggestCountries != null && biggestCountries.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < biggestCountries.length; i++) {
                if(countryData[i][COUNTRY_AGE_FOUNDED] >= min &&
                   countryData[i][COUNTRY_AGE_FOUNDED] <= max) {
                    indexes[countriesMatched++] = i;
                }
            }
            countriesFoundedBetween = new String[countriesMatched];
            for (int i = 0; i < countriesMatched; i++) {
                countriesFoundedBetween[i] = biggestCountries[indexes[i]][COUNTRY_NAME];
            }
        }
        else {
            countriesFoundedBetween = new String[0];
        }
        return countriesFoundedBetween;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] result = getCountriesFoundedBetween(1950, 1980);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}
```

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
[India, Nigeria, Bangladesh]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you name a Class `BigestCountries` still it has an attribute `biggestCountries` which is an array, holds information about biggest countries, I think you are not utilizing the potential of OO.
2. You can use Class to represent the data of a `Country`. With data encapsulation, you can get rid of nested array thus nested loop and control flow statement (break, continue etc), lookup index constant, keep sync-ing the index between `biggestCountries` and `countryData` etc.
3. Your code doing the same task twice. The first loop count the matched country and initialize a array. The second loop actually put the matched country name to the array.
4. Java collection framework provide data structure with dynamic size. I use `ArrayList` here
5. I think `ageFound` should be named `yearFound`?

Refactored Your code

Country.java

```
public class Country {

    private String name;
    private int population;
    private int yearFound;
    private String continent;

    public Country(String name, String continent, int year, int population) {
        this.name = name;
        this.population = population;
        this.continent = continent;
        this.yearFound = year;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }

    public String getContinent() {
        return continent;
    }

    public void setContinent(String continent) {
        this.continent = continent;
    }

    public int getYearFound() {
        return yearFound;
    }

    public void setYearFound(int yearFound) {
        this.yearFound = yearFound;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country [name=" + name + ", population=" + population + ", yearFound=" + yearFound + ", continent="
                + continent + "]";
    }

}
```

BiggestCountries.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class BiggestCountries {

    private List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>() {
        {
            add(new Country("China", "Asia", 1949, 1433783686));
            add(new Country("Canada", "North America", 1867, 37590000));
            add(new Country("United States", "North America", 1776, 328200000));
        }
    };

    public List<Country> getCountriesFoundedBetween(int min, int max) {
        List<Country> matchedCountry = new ArrayList<Country>();
        Iterator<Country> itrCoutnry = countries.iterator();

        while (itrCoutnry.hasNext()) {
            Country country = itrCoutnry.next();
            int yearFound = country.getYearFound();
            if (min < yearFound && max > yearFound) {
                matchedCountry.add(country);
            }
        }
        return matchedCountry;
    }

}
```

Test Run

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Country> matchedCountries = new BiggestCountries().getCountriesFoundedBetween(1700, 1899);
    System.out.println(matchedCountries);
}
```

Result

```
[Country [name=Canada, population=37590000, yearFound=1867, continent=North America], Country [name=United States, population=328200000, yearFound=1776, continent=North America]]
```